# US Student Overstayed 3 Days On a Tier 4 Visa

Tags: visas, uk, applications, overstaying

In April 2017, I overstayed by 3 days on an expired Tier 4 student visa. A long story short, I was a victim of a serious crime while in the UK and was granted further time by my university to complete work. The aftermath was heavily emotional and psychologically exhausting, not an ideal situation to finish the work, but I did it and down to the wire. As I pressed charges, the defendant was found guilty on all charges.

The extended deadline given by the university was 2 days after my visa expired and I left on the 3rd day of overstay. I will be applying for another Tier 4 soon and wondered if there will be any issues with the visa application if I can provide evidence and documentation of the extenuating circumstance. How do I and what should I present for the explanation for the overstay on the application?

It may be worth noting that I returned to the UK in July 2017 for graduation and again in April 2018 without any trouble from the border officials. I appreciate any help with this. Thank you.

Comment: I’m not sure what else you can present other than to disclose the overstay and why you didn’t leave by the deadline given by the university, and evidence of the circumstances. For example, the case number, any correspondence with the police, court documents, plus paperwork from the university regarding the deadline extension.

Comment: Update: Thanks again, @Traveller! My application was successful and I received the visa fairly quickly without premium service (within 9 days). Best wishes!